# Why recursively search files in folder doesn't work correctly

Tags: python, recursion

I need help to understand why this piece of code didn't work as expect.

My directory structure looks like this:

```
|- tryWalkDir.py

   TryCPP/
   TryCPP/tryHashMap/
   TryCPP/tryHashMap/tryHashMap.cpp
   TryCPP/tryHashMap/tryHashMap.o*
```

The script - tryWalkDir.py is intented to search all the .cpp files. I don't know why

[TryCPP/tryHashMap/tryHashMap.cpp,TryCPP/tryHashMap/tryHashMap.cpp] collect 2 times?

```
Enter into depth:0, folder:TryCPP
folder:TryCPP, cur:TryCPP, sub:['tryHashMap'], files:[], depth:0
recresively call - s:tryHashMap
Enter into depth:1, folder:TryCPP/tryHashMap
folder:TryCPP/tryHashMap, cur:TryCPP/tryHashMap, sub:[], files:
['tryHashMap.cpp', 'tryHashMap.o'], depth:1
process tryHashMap.cpp
append tryHashMap.cpp
process tryHashMap.o
Exit on depth:1, folder:TryCPP/tryHashMap
folder:TryCPP, cur:TryCPP/tryHashMap, sub:[], files:['tryHashMap.cpp', 'tryHashMap.o'], depth:0
process tryHashMap.cpp
append tryHashMap.cpp
process tryHashMap.o
Exit on depth:0, folder:TryCPP
['TryCPP/tryHashMap/tryHashMap.cpp', 'TryCPP/tryHashMap/tryHashMap.cpp']
```

### tryWalkDir.py

```
class Cell(object):
    def __init__(self, fn, ext):    
       self.fn = fn
       self.ext = ext
       self.fl = [] #list all the files

    def collect_files(self, folder, depth=0):
    ''' collect all the folders containing corresponding extension scripts '''
        print 'Enter into depth:%d, folder:%s' % (depth,folder)

        # level one folder name should start with 'Try' or 'try'
        if depth == 1:
            filename = os.path.basename(folder)[:3]
            if filename in ['Try','try']:
                pass
            else:
                print 'L1 Dir - {0} must start with [Try,try], depth:{1}'.format(filename,depth)
            return

        for cur, sub, files in os.walk(folder):
            print 'folder:{}, cur:{}, sub:{}, files:{}, depth:{}'.format(folder,cur,sub,files,depth)

            #filter out all the files
            #[ self.fl.append(cur+'/'+f) for f in files if os.path.splitext(f)[1][1:] == self.ext ]
            for f in files:
                print 'process %s' % f
                if os.path.splitext(f)[1][1:] == self.ext:
                    print 'append %s' % f
                    self.fl.append(cur+'/'+f)

            #if sub:
            for s in sub:
                print 'recresively call - s:{}'.format(s)
                self.collect_files(cur+'/'+s,depth+1)

        print 'Exit on depth:%d, folder:%s' % (depth,folder)


    def start(self):
        self.collect_files(self.fn,0)
        #print self.fl


def main():
    cell = Cell('TryCPP','cpp')
    cell.start()
    print cell.fl

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Comment: Fix your indentation please. I find it hard to believe that you have a `for` loop in the middle of your class body, especially since it references `self`.

Comment: Thanks, Mad. I fix the indentation.

Comment: `if filename in ['Try','try']: pass, else: ...` can be `if filename not in ['Try','try']: ...`

Comment: When I run your code as-is with the example file structure you've provided above, I get `['TryCPP/tryHashMap/tryHashMap.cpp']`. Are you sure it isn't working?

Comment: @mwm314. There is definitely a mistake. The call is doubly recursive. Are you sure you have two layers of directories?

Comment: I agree that you don't need recursion with `os.walk`, it does that for you. It makes sense that it would be added twice. But I am not getting the double output...I'm on windows 10.

Comment: Thanks for Mad and mwm314's comments. By removing recursively calling as Mad's suggestion, the output is correct. Interesting thing is that I also cannot get double output using my own Linux. Is there some Python version related issue? Python 2.7.12 - Correct output. Python 2.7.6 - Incorrect output.

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening because you are calling [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) multiple times without realizing it. `os.walk` recurses for you into subdirectories. However, you then call `self.collect_files(cur+'/'+s,depth+1)` for each subdirectory in your current directory. This will actually cause a file at depth `N` to appear `N` times in your output array.

To fix your code, simply remove the loop

```
for s in sub:
    print 'recresively call - s:{}'.format(s)
    self.collect_files(cur+'/'+s,depth+1)
```

As an aside, you should probably use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) instead of manually concatenating slashes throughout your code. For example, `self.fl.append(cur+'/'+f)` could read `self.fl.append(join(cur, f))`. This is the way suggested by the `os.walk` documentation:

> To get a full path (which begins with top) to a file or directory in dirpath, do `os.path.join(dirpath, name)`.